# What is a thread-specific os.chdir and mkdir in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, operating-system

I have several threads each of which is changing working directories and occasionally creating new ones in specific working directories, copying/moving files etc in these directories. Think e.g.:

```
def thread1:
  while True:
    os.chdir('dir')
    os.mkdir('newdir')
    os.system('mv *.png newdir/')
    do something

def thread2:
  while True:
    os.chdir('another-dir')
    os.mkdir('another-newdir')
    os.system('mv *.png another-newdir/')
    do something
```

I've read that chdir, mkdir functions are not specific to threads but global. What is a way to accomplish this? I can try to use absolute paths but is that the best solution?

Comment: A quick way to solve it is to never call ``os.chdir()``.  In your case it would become ``os.mkdir('dir/newdir'); os.system('cd dir && mv *.png newdir/')``.  Note that the ``cd`` is inside the shell command.

Comment: Yet Another solution --only on Linux-- is to use `unshare(CLONE_FS)` function, but that definitely requires writing C or using ctypes/cffi.

Answer (score 12):

The working directory is an information of the **process**, hence all threads share the same working directory. You **must** work with absolute paths if you want to use multiple threads.

You can obtain absolute paths quite easily using the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module.

An other thing that you may consider is using python's standard library to do the copying instead of calling external processes.

See for example:

- [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html)
- [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#glob)

Comment: Probably not very useful, but there exists a solution on Linux (which does not exist on other OSes, and is not exposed to Python AFAIK): do ``man mkdirat`` to find out more.

Comment: @ArminRigo, [mkdirat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdir.html) is POSIX.

Comment: @pilcrow: You're right.  Also, it has been added to Python 3.3 where you can say for example `os.open(..., dir_fd=fd)`.

Comment: @ArminRigo I didn't know about `mkdirat`, but I'd still prefer avoiding doing this and explicitly use absolute paths.

Answer (score 5):

The Current Working Directory at OS level usually is process specific, not per thread.  (Linux: see [unshare](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unshare.2.html))

Python internal file operations mostly can be re-written to use a `os.path.join()` and avoid `chdir()`.

When this is not possible, e.g. for unchangeable code, for `RExec` kind of sandbox executions or so, then you could provide a virtual `os` module, `open` functions etc. which do path adjustment behind the scenes.

For calling external programs, you can provide a `cwd=...` argument in  subprocess.Popen() calls and friends.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using multiple threads, you could as well use multiple processes which solves the issue.

Look for [`os.fork()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fork).

I have backup script that work on multiple disks, and by using a process per disk, I can make sure disk utilization stays at 100% on all disks.

There are a variety of other libraries to manage process pools in similar ways to thread pools, my favorite is the [concurrent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures) package.